# Returns function results from list with different data structure. (using lapply or sapply function)

Tags: r, list, lapply, sapply

I'm struggling with list.

I have a list with different data structure as below

```
mylist<-list(dat1=c(rep(5:9, times=2)), dat2=seq(50,120,by=6), dat3=data.frame(a=c(1:4),b=c(-1:2)))
```

What I want to do is to apply a function to each element of mylist by using

`lapply` or `sapply` function.
like `lapply(mylist, function(x) mean(x) )`

But here is my problem.
dat3 in mylist is data frame and it has two variables, but `lapply` and `sapply` function like returns only one maximum and average values.

Outputs what I want to get are

```
 $dat1             
    max    mean 
     9       7
 $dat2
    max   mean
     116    83
 $dat3
      a              b
    max mean     max mean 
     4   2.5      2   0.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
lapply(mylist,function(x){
  lapply(data.frame(x),function(y){
    data.frame(max=max(y),mean=mean(y))
  })
})

$dat1
$dat1$x
  max mean
1   9    7


$dat2
$dat2$x
  max mean
1 116   83


$dat3
$dat3$a
  max mean
1   4  2.5

$dat3$b
  max mean
1   2  0.5
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. I replicate your code separately, like, `tmp<-lapply(mylist,data.frame)` and then   `lapply(tmp,function(y){data.frame(max=max(y),mean=mean(y))})`. But I  got 'NAs` in some columns. Do you know why is that?

Comment: @wan Must be something in the data, do you have any missing values or non-numeric values?

Comment: No, I use `mylist` which I describe above. Have you tried the  code `tmp<-lapply(mylist,data.frame) and then lapply(tmp,function(y){data.frame(max=max(y),mean=mean(y))})`??

Comment: @wan I see, your code is not equivalent to mine - it changes the structure of the data so it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You can use recursive `lapply` (`rapply`)

```
rapply(mylist, function(x) c(max = max(x), mean = mean(x)), how = "list")

#$dat1
# max mean 
#   9    7 

#$dat2
# max mean 
# 116   83 

#$dat3
#$dat3$a
# max mean 
# 4.0  2.5 

#$dat3$b
# max mean 
# 2.0  0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

another option

```
library(purrr)
library(psych)
map(.x = mylist, .f = ~psych::describe(.x))
```